# How to delete or Exit Particular Groupchat using XMPP in iOS

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework, node-xmpp

Currently i am making chat application and i required to delete Particular groupchat.

To delete group i tried 2 solutions but are not working.

***1st solution i applied  as follow :-***

```
xmppRoomStorage = [[XMPPRoomMemoryStorage alloc] init];

XMPPJID *roomJid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:self.strnameofgroup];

_xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:xmppRoomStorage jid:roomJid];

[_xmppRoom removeDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

[_xmppRoom deactivate];

[_xmppRoom leaveRoom];
```

### **2nd solution i applied as follow :-**

1st fetch all members in the groupchat and then all members left groupchat  manually but it also not working.

```
NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin"];

 NSXMLElement *item = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"item"];

 [item addAttributeWithName:@"affiliation" stringValue:@"member"];

 [item addAttributeWithName:@"jid" stringValue:@"jid to remove"];

 [query addChild:item];

XMPPIQ *RemoveUser = [[XMPPIQ alloc] initWithType:@"set" to:[XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@",dialuser2,kSIPDomain]] elementID:@"some random id" child:query];

  [SharedAppDelegate.xmppStream sendElement:RemoveUser];
```

So please help me if any solution to delete particular group.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the configure of your room?  Is it a persistent room?

If yes, then the room must be destroyed by the owner.

```
xmppRoom.destroyRoom()
```

Otherwise, the room will be automatically deleted if all the members left.

Comment: Thanks for help and my room configure is persistent so i will try to destory room.

Comment: [_xmppRoom destroyRoom]; called but not delete/exit group.if possible then please give me steps of delete/exit group.

Comment: It was working to me and tested.  Read this doc, http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#roomconfig.  Make sure only Owner can destroy the room.  You can check the xmppStreamDelegate and see if there is any error response back.

Comment: hello dichen,
i tried your code and successfully delete Room but now i need remove particular user from Room.
For that i have tried many code but not work.
if you have any information or code then please help me.
thank you

Comment: Could you tell me what have you done to remove a member?  Seriously you need to read through the XEP-0045 I mentioned above, here is the tag for modifying members, https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#modifymember.  According to the doc, Admin Role (Owner by default is) can modify the member list.  Unfortunately XmppFramework doesn't implement this, you need to make up your own iq and send it to server.

Comment: i used NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin"];
 NSXMLElement *item = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"item"];
 [item addAttributeWithName:@"affiliation" stringValue:@"member"];
 [item addAttributeWithName:@"jid" stringValue:@"put jid which you to remove"];
 [query addChild:item];
XMPPIQ *RemoveUser = [[XMPPIQ alloc] initWithType:@"set" to:[XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@",dialuser2,kSIPDomain]] elementID:@"some random id" child:query];
  [SharedAppDelegate.xmppStream sendElement:RemoveUser];

Comment: I thought you want to remove the user from member list, right?  [item addAttributeWithName:@"affiliation" stringValue:@"member"]; means you are setting the user as `Member`.  Have you read  https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#modifymember?

Comment: yes i read but i will make Room Delete functionality same like Whats app.For that i need your help.So if any suggestion then please give me.

Comment: I have pointed it out earlier, Admin can modify the member list, what you need to do it take the member out of the member list. See how the doc says, it's well documented  I guess maybe you should  set the affiliation to 'None' instead of 'member'.  Myself never try this functionality, so not positive.

Comment: currently i developed Group Destroyed functionality and it's working properly but i need exit functionality.
For example,i made one Group and invite 3 user and all 3 user join group.After Some time i exit from group that time any one member assign as Group admin.In short Group Exit functionality i will develop.

Comment: You mean you want to `Promote a random of rest as Owner` when`current Owner quit the room`?

Comment: yes dichen you are right.so if any idea or suggestion then please help me.

Comment: @DivyaPatel see the other post of you, I added some comments

Comment: yes i saw your comment and currently i am trying to implement this in code.

Comment: hello dichen,
are you here?i have one confusion.
In IQ tag which value pass in from and to element.
i passed current user id in from and group name passed in to.

Comment: //random user assign as owner of the group
Set IQ

NSXMLElement *ownerIQ=[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"iq"];
                                    [ownerIQ addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:[SharedAppDelegate.xmppStream myJID].full];
                                    [ownerIQ addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:self.strnameofgroup];
                                    [ownerIQ addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"member1"];
                                    [ownerIQ addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"set"];

Comment: //random user assign as owner of the group Set query
 NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin"];

Comment: //random user assign as owner of the group Set item  NSXMLElement *item = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"item"];
                                [item addAttributeWithName:@"affiliation" stringValue:@"owner"];
                               [item addAttributeWithName:@"jid" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@",strphonenumber,kSIPDomain]];
                                    [query addChild:item];
                                   [ownerIQ addChild:query];
                                  [SharedAppDelegate.xmppStream sendElement:ownerIQ];

Comment: Note that the userJid in a room should be "roomName@conference.hostName/username", that's different than myJID (username@hostName)

Comment: <iq from="nrewwww%20uiop%20hjkl%207890@conference.56.19.114.156/9190333225566" to="nrewwww%20uiop%20hjkl%207890@conference.56.19.114.156" id="member1" type="set"></iq>
now it's proper or not?

Comment: I guess no, show me your RoomJID and UserJID individually, removing the %20 encode.

Comment: RoomJID :- abc new@conference.56.19.114.156
UserJID :- 9190333225566@56.19.114.156
Remove UserJID :- 9190333225566@56.19.114.156
Assign as member JID :- 9190333224466@56.19.114.156

Comment: hello dichen,
it's not working :( please share any other code available.
i have implement group delete same like whats app.
i have create roomconfig_persistentroom.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have code in hand.  What you want to do has been covered by the document, something must be wrong, but without the full code I can't tell.

Comment: One thing is you need to promote the other owner before you kick yourself out.

Comment: i have create roomconfig_persistentroom.so this  permission effect when delete Group ?

Comment: from: abc new@conference.56.19.114.156/9190333225566, to: abc new@conference.56.19.114.156

Comment: Printing description of ownerIQ:
<iq from=“abc new@conference.56.19.114.156/9190333225566" to=“abc new@conference.56.19.114.156" id="member1" type="set"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin"><item affiliation="owner" jid="9190333224466@56.19.114.156"></item></query></iq>
Printing description of removeIQ:
<iq from="abc new@conference.56.19.114.156/9190333225566" to="abc new@conference.56.19.114.156" id="member2" type="set"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin"><item affiliation="none" jid="9190333225566@56.19.114.156"></item></query></iq>
is it proper?

Comment: looks right to me. If not working, try see if there is any message or error comes back in the xmppStream delegates, you should see some error back if it doesn't work.

Comment: ok i am working on this and if any solution found then inform you.Also you have found any solution for that then please inform me.

Comment: Hello dichen,
i have found fault.Group member/owner not delete because didreceiveIQ not called when group member/owner delete.

Comment: yes, it's working if I am the admin of that group, but if I am not admin for that group and want to remove or exit from the group then how I can do it?

Comment: how to exit from room by member ?